# Не запускается PHP-скрипт, помогите найти ошибку

Tags: php

```
<?php

header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
set_time_limit(-1);

$minViewers = 50;
$maxScan = 2000;

$filenameRu = 'rusteams.txt';
$filenameAll = 'steams.txt';

// ---------------------------------------------

file_put_contents($filenameRu, '');
file_put_contents($filenameAll, '');

for ($offset = 0; $offset <= $maxScan; $offset += 100){
echo "$offset/$maxScan 
", PHP_EOL;
flush();
ob_flush();
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://twitch.tv/"));
foreach ($json->streams as $st){
if ($st->channel->language=='ru' && $st->viewers > $minViewers) file_put_contents($filenameRu, $st->channel->name.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filenameAll, $st->channel->name.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}

}

// удаляем дубли и сортируем полученные файлы стримов
clearAndSort($filenameAll);
clearAndSort($filenameRu);

echo "[Finished]";

function clearAndSort ($filename){
$steams = file($filename);
$steams = array_unique($steams);
sort($steams);
array_shift($steams);
file_put_contents($filename, implode($steams, ''));
}
```

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Z:\home\localhost\www\twitch\tw_get_channels.php on line 23

Comment: Вау, твитч трансляция в wpf приложении?

Comment: Отформатируйте пошалуйста код - например Ctrl-K.

Comment: @ivan Что непонятного в предупреждении? в $json->streams явно не то что можно итерировать, смотрите что в нем приходит

Comment: Разве "https://twitch.tv/" в формате JSON? У вас json_decode null выдает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents("https://twitch.tv/")` получает HTML, а вы пытаетесь преобразовать этот HTML из JSON в объект. 
Вторая ошибка - использование

```
flush();
ob_flush();
```

Без ob_start, да и вообще не понятно зачем.
Вообщем, ваш код вообще не должен работать.